# Подготовленные запросы PDO

Tags: pdo

Делаю подготовленные запросы и почему-то возвращает пустой массив

```
$page = intval($page);
    $per_page = Functions::getSiteSettings('news_per_page');
    $offset = ($page - 1) * $per_page;
    $db = Db::getConnection();
    $result = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT ? OFFSET ?');
    $result->execute(array($per_page, $offset));

    print_r($result->fetchAll());
```

а вот в таком виде работает:

```
$db = Db::getConnection();
    $result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM news WHERE id=?");

    $result->execute(array($id));


    $row = $result->fetch();
    return $row;
```

В чем дело,ведь все переменные работают нормально и запрос в базу, а вот выборка нет?

Comment: mysql не позволяет использовать подставляемые значения в limit и offset, возможно какие то другие СУБД так же не позволяют

Comment: Что делать-то тогда?

Comment: подставлять значения непосредственно в текст запроса (не забыв проверить, что они числа

Comment: добавил $db->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false ); и заработало, но эта строчка,как я понимаю,выключает проверку типа, а можно ли привести целочисленному значению в самой строчке запроса?

Comment: По хорошему это надо делать только в случае использования limit и offset. А в случае любых других запросов этого делать не надо, ибо возможно снижение производительности. Так что на счет глобального включения на все соединение я бы хорошо подумал ... и сделал бы скорее для limit исключение в виде прямой подстановки, смысла от передачи через execute нет. pdo просто за вас подставит значение

Answer (score 0):

Почитайте [тут](http://phpfaq.ru/pdo#limit) - там много полезного, в том числе и по вашему вопросу.

1. вариант предложен в комментариях уже ([Anry Reese](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/235176/anry-reese)):

   ```
   $db->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false );
   ```

   либо можно устанавливать параметр сразу при подключении:

   ```
   $options = array(
       ...
       PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false
       ...
   );
   $connection = new PDO($dsn, $username, $passwd, $options);
   ```
2. Вариант описан [по ссылке](http://phpfaq.ru/pdo#limit) в самом начале. Можно связывать переменные в запросе [по-отдельности](https://secure.php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.bindvalue.php), указывая конкретный тип каждой из них:

   ```
   $page = intval($page);
   $per_page = Functions::getSiteSettings('news_per_page');
   $offset = ($page - 1) * $per_page;
   $db = Db::getConnection();
   // вот так вот:
   $result = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT :limit OFFSET :offset');
   $result->bindValue(':limit', $per_page, PDO::PARAM_INT);
   $result->bindValue(':offset', $offset, PDO::PARAM_INT);
   $result->execute();

   print_r($result->fetchAll());
   ```
3. Вариант также предложен в комментариях ([Mike](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/194569/mike)), в этом случае напрямую подставлять параметры в строку.

К слову, если Вы далее захотите добавить ещё динамическую подстановку параметра в `ORDER BY`, то Вам в любом случае придётся использовать либо третий вариант, либо второй (причем лучше третий, так как во втором хоть и можно подставлять параметром номер соответствующего поля, но нужно будет как-то подставлять ещё и `ASC/DESC` - а это можно будет сделать только прямой подстановкой в строку).